# How to pass command line arguments to C code with WebAssembly and JS?

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

I'm trying to run some small C demos on the web with WebAssembly and pure JS, and I'm compiling my code using WASI-SDK/WASI-libc:

`clang --target=wasm32-unknown-wasi --sysroot=<sysroot> -nostartfiles -O3 -flto -Wl,--no-entry -Wl,--export=malloc -Wl,--export-all -Wl,--lto-O3 src.c -o src.wasm`

I'm then using [this small JS library](https://github.com/rob-blackbourn/example-wasm-stdout-stderr) to implement the WASI functions. This works fine for printing with stdout, and I've even tested passing strings and other types into different functions. But I can't figure out how to pass an array of strings into `main` as an argument.

I don't want to use Node or Emscripten, which is why I went with a minimal JS implementation.

Edit:

To add command line arguments, I removed both `-nostartfiles` and `-Wl,--no-entry` from my compiler call and implemented `args_get` and `args_sizes_get` from the WASI standard. From there, it was as simple as calling `_start` from the `wasm`'s exported functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use WASI then the way to pass args to main is to implement the `wasi_snapshot_preview1.args_get` and `wasi_snapshot_preview1.args_sizes_get` syscalls which are used by WASI programs to access the argv values.  In that case you would want to call `_start` rather than `main`.

If you want to bypass that and call `main` directly you would need to somehow allocate and array of `char *` pointers in the linear memory which you could then pass as your argv value.   The problem that you face if you try to take this approach is that allocating memory (e.g. via malloc) before calling main is hard.  My advise would be to go with the first method which is to call `_start` and implement that `wasi` syscall needed to access `argv`.   (You can call also then remove the `-Wl,--no-entry` from your link command).

Comment: I assumed it would be start but I wasn't sure. How would I specify the entry point? Removing `-Wl,--no-entry` gives `wasm-ld: error: entry symbol not defined (pass --no-entry to suppress): _start`

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it by removing both `-nostartfiles` and `-Wl,--no-entry`